# Regex: how to use re.sub with variable number of elements?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm trying to replace {x;y} patterns in a text corpus with "x or y", except that the number of elements is variable, so sometimes there will be 3 or more elements i.e. {x;y;z} (max is 9).

I'm trying to do this with regex, but I'm not sure how to do this such that I can replace according to the number of elements present. So I mean like, if I use a regex with a variable component like the following

`part = '(;[\w\s]+)'
regex = '\(([\w\s]+);([\w\s]+){}?\)'.format(part)
re.sub(regex,/1 or /2 or /3, text)`

I will sometimes get an additional 'or' (and more if I increase the number of variable elements) when there are only 2 elements present in the braces, which I don't want. The alternative is to do this many times with different number of variable parts but the code would be very clunky. I'm wondering if there are any ways I could achieve this with regex methods? Would appreciate any ideas.

I'm using python3.5 with spyder.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to replace `{x;y}` by `{x or y}` or does it have to be `x or y` (without the braces)?

Comment: My intention is to remove the braces as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is just a bit too much for a regular search-and-replace action, so I would recommend passing in a function to dynamically generate the replacement string.

```
import re

text = 'There goes my {cat;dog} playing in the {street;garden}.'

def replacer(m):
    return m.group(1).replace(';', ' or ')

output = re.sub(r'\{((\w;?)*\w)\}', replacer, text)

print(output)
```

Output:

> There goes my cat or dog playing in the street or garden.